# Why declare a variable as a new Object?

Tags: javascript

As a beginner, working with existing code, I've come across the following:

```
var foo = {};
```

which I believe is equivalent to:

```
var foo = new Object();
```

I was under the impression that any variable was automatically an Object, so what would be the purpose of specifically coding that, rather than just declaring an empty variable:

```
var foo;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was under the impression that any variable was automatically an Object

That is a mistaken impression. If you declare a variable and do not assign it a value, it is initialised to `undefined` (as mention [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x12.2) and described [in detail](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5)), which is not an object (it's a primitive value):

```
var foo;
console.log(foo); // undefined
```

If you were to attempt to set a property of an undefined variable you would receive a TypeError:

```
var foo;
foo.example = "hello"; // TypeError: Cannot set property 'example' of undefined
```

However, if you assign an empty object to that variable, the above code will succeed:

```
var foo = {}; // Now refers to an empty object (equivalent to `new Object()`)
foo.example = "hello";
console.log(foo); // '{example:"hello"}'
```

---

I believe your understanding probably stems from the common misunderstanding that "everything in JavaScript is an object". **This is not true**. Many things in JavaScript are objects, but primitive values are not. For example:

```
var a = "hello"; // String primitive, not an object
var b = new String("hello"); // String instance, object
var c = 10; // Number primitive, not an object
var d = true; // Boolean primitive, not an object
var e; // Undefined value, not an object
var f = null; // Null value, not an object
```

Comment: Good answer..if we initialize the variable that becomes object?

Comment: @sasi - If you assign an object to the variable then it refers to an object. If you assign something else to it (e.g. a string literal) then it will refer to that.

Comment: That spec reference is a bit turgid, I think the section on [variable statements](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) is a bit easier.

Comment: Note that you can initialize the variable as a primitive type, not all variables in javascript have to either be undefined or an object. The string, number and boolean are primitive types. These primitives get wrapped in theyr corresponding object automatically when you invoke a method (Number, String and Boolean object)

Comment: @RobG - Agreed, I didn't notice that the variable statements section mentioned it in passing. I've added a link to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @cernunnos—note that variables have a value, it's the value that has a [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8).

Comment: @JamesAllardice Figured it would be down to some novice misunderstanding. Thanks very much for a good clear and thorough explanation. I'm trying to avoid making too many easy assumptions as I learn!

Comment: @RobG if you are going to get technical then you have to say that variables are a reference to a value that has a type, javascript just happens to pass variables by reference (and copy primitive values) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

James's answer is correct. In case he's throwing too much info too quickly (refer back to it later, if so), here's a quick summary.

You are correct in this: var foo = {} and var foo = new Object() are not only equivalent, the results are identical. Only use object literals. (ignore new Object(), new Array(), etc).

var foo; does nothing other than declare a variable. It is 'undefined' by default.

Answer (score -1):

var foo = new Object() also gives the new object a prototype property which can be used to manipulate object inheritance and call standard object functions defined by javascript

see here for details on how you can manipulate the object.protype:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: Functions have prototypes. Objects have constructors. Constructors are functions. {} and new Object() are identical. Use the literal ({}) syntax. var f = {}; f.constructor; //function Object(){} f.constructor.prototype //Object {}

Comment: O yea sorry I wasnt thinking